# Doctrine2 mapping error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

here are my classes :

First the modelMetaKey class :

```
  /**
    * @Entity(repositoryClass="models\repository\meta\modelMetaKey")
    * @table(name="model_meta_key", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columns={"meta_id", "mkey_id"})})
    */
    class modelMetaKey extends \models\entity
    {
        /**
        * The meta
        * @var \models\core\model\meta
        * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\core\model\meta", inversedBy="modelKeys")
        * @JoinColumn(name="meta_id", referencedColumnName="id");
        */
        private $meta;
        ...
    }
```

Second the meta class :

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="models\repository\core\model\meta")
 * @table(name="core_model_meta")
 */
class meta extends model
{
    /**
     * Keys defined for this model
     * @var \models\meta\modelMetaKey"
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="models\meta\modelMetaKey", mappedBy="meta")
     */
    private $modelKeys;
    ...
}
```

When i run doctrine orm:validate-schema
I get this message :

```
Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'models\meta\modelMetaKey' mapping is invalid:
* The association models\meta\modelMetaKey#meta refers to the inverse side field models\core\model\meta#modelKeys which does not exist.
```

i understand that doctrine does not find $modelKeys in my meta class, but i do not understand why because it is there !?

Notes : 
model and \models\entity are of course derivated from a mapped supperclass ;)

I am going crazy with this error... If someone has an explanation or better a solution, please share

Answer (score 0):

Is this the actual code?:

```
/**
 * Keys defined for this model
 * @var \models\meta\modelMetaKey"
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="models\meta\modelMetaKey", mappedBy="meta")
 */
private $modelKeys;
```

because I imagine the `"` after `\models\meta\modelMetaKey` could invalidate the following mapping annotation ... but it's just a guess.

(this would be a comment if I had the right to write those)